# How can I add some wiggle room (lower padding or margin) to my HTML button?

Tags: c#, html

I'm dynamically creating Controls and adding them to a Web Part.

When I do this:

```
this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
Button btnSave = new Button();
btnSave.Text = "Save";
btnSave.Click += new EventHandler(btnSave_Click);
this.Controls.Add(btnSave);
this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />")); // <= this does nothing
```

...the button sits down on the very bottom of the web part:

[image]

(note that adding a "br" is ignored)

If I add this:

```
btnSave.BorderWidth = 6;
```

...it does provide a border around the button, but it's not the same color as the background -- it's black, as you can see:

[image]

How can I add some space below the button without the border having a color other than the background?

### UPDATE

I wanted to try the btnSave.Style.MarginBottom code suggested, but there is no "MarginBottom" subproperty of the Button's Style property, as can be seen here:

[image]

### UPDATE 2

When I tried Mohammad's latest suggestion:

```
btnSave.BorderColor = this.BorderColor;
```

...I got, "The type 'System.Drawing.Color' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Drawing. . ."

So I tried that:

```
using System.Drawing;
```

...but trying to compile resulted in: "The type or namespace name 'Drawing' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the ticket (inspired by a code snippet (using "div") [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh228018(v=office.14).aspx):

```
//this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />")); // <= this does nothing
HtmlGenericControl breakingSpace = new HtmlGenericControl("br");
this.Controls.Add(breakingSpace);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
btnSave.style.marginBottom = "10px";
```

you can change the number to whatever looks good!

Comment: Please see my update (there is no "MarginBottom" property of Style).

Comment: If you're using javascript, it should, even if you don't see it in autocomplete. Maybe you're not seeing it because you typed a capital "M.' Check: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp. Also, .style is all lowercase.

Comment: This is C#, not jQuery.

Comment: Sorry about that, that's definitely on me. Can you by any chance try the style.BorderColor property to set the color to that of the background?

Comment: I believe that you need to add a reference to System.Drawing.dll (in solution explorer - aka project files - right click the 'references' folder and find System.Drawing, should be in the .NET tab

Comment: I have no System.Drawing in the NET tab; maybe because this is a "different animal" (Sharepoint)?